# Discord.js - Get a bots server count (not my bot, others bot)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

posting a discord bots server count.

So im making a discord bot list and im having a hard time finding a way to display a discord bots server count, if anyone knows how please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I think top.gg uses a different way to get that like when you submit a bot you have to enter your application id so the probably use an application and not a bot

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible unless you have access to said bot since Discord doesn't reveal a user's guilds to anyone who asks.

Comment: then how is it possible on top.gg or vcodes.xyz

From top.gg - https://i.imgur.com/j1kgKYz.png
From vcodes - https://i.imgur.com/B9aLLCl.png